# House hunting area background checking tools

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps, mashup

I'm looking to buy a property very soon and want to make an informed choice. As such I am searching for tools to aid me in researching the surrounding areas of houses I am interested in. The kind of information I'm after is flood risk/crime risk/neighbours risk (difficult to assess ie children = noise etc).

So far I have discovered the following resources:

http://houseprices.co.uk/

http://environment-agency.gov.uk/homeandleisure/37793.aspx

http://maps.police.uk/view/dorset/

http://www.neighbourhood.statistics.gov.uk/dissemination/LeadHome.do;jessionid=ac1f930d30d6179457030e7348e5bf27f6e25d1d5db1?m=0&s=1285270427272&enc=1&nsjs=true&nsck=true&nssvg=false&nswid=1680

However I'm really looking for more! The best solution would be a Google/Bing/whoever map mashup of this data into a super map so I could make a really informed decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.upmystreet.com/ might be useful

> Find house prices & trends, schools, crime rates, local businesses, home advice & more on UpMyStreet.

Answer (score 0):

[Home Finder](http://www.homefinder.com/)

[About My Place](http://www.aboutmyplace.co.uk/)

[Google Real Estate for Professionals](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/realestate/agents/maps.html)